# Setting and getting an asp Listbox as a session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have an asp listbox which generates items depending on what the user selects. This works fine. My question is, how can I store this listbox as a session and retrieving the session?

Answer (score 0):

To store things in a session...

```
Session["MyKey"] = "My Value";
```

To retrieve things from a session

```
string myValue = Session["MyKey"];
```

You may have to cast as necessary if you're not using strings.

So what you might do...

```
//store
Session["SelectedValue"] = MyListBox.SelectedValue;
//later retrieve
string selectedValue = Session["SelectedValue"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend storing the list box itself in a Session variable. Instead try storing the generated items in session. Here's an example of storing a list in Session.

```
private List<object> _items;
public List<object> Items
{
    get
    {
        if (_items == null)
        {
            _items = Session["ListBoxItems"] as List<object>;
        }
        return _items;
     }
    set
    {
         Session["ListBoxItems"] = value;            
    }
}
```